# GPUImage gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient crash using GPUImageFilter

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImageFilter in a chain, and most of the time it works OK. I've recently come across a few random crashes that match the symptoms in this [github issue](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/197) (albeit I'm using GPUImageFilter not live capture or video). I'm trying to find a suitable method that can ensure I've cleared the frame buffer and any other GPUImage-related activities in `willResignActive`.

Currently I have:

```
[[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] purgeAllUnassignedFramebuffers];
```

Is this sufficient? Should I use something else instead/in addition to?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated there, seeing `gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient` in a stack trace almost always is due to OpenGL ES operations being performed while your application is in the background or is just about to go to the background.

To deal with this, you need to guarantee that all GPUImage-related work is finished before your application heads to the background. You'll want to listen for delegate notifications that your application is heading to the background, and make sure all processing is complete before that delegate callback exits. The suggestion there by henryl is one way to ensure this. Add the following near the end of your delegate callback:

```
runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{
    // Do some operation
});
```

What that will do is inject a synchronous block into the video processing pipeline (which runs on a background queue). Your delegate callback will block the main thread at that point until this block has a chance to execute, guaranteeing that all processing blocks before it have finished. That will make sure all pending operations are done (assuming you don't add new ones) before your application heads to the background.

There is a slight chance of this introducing a deadlock in your application, but I don't think any of my code in the processing pipeline calls back into the main queue. You might want to watch out for that, because if I do still have something in there that does that, this will lock your application. That internal code would need to be fixed if so.

Comment: Great Brad, thanks. Any suggestions for what to perform inside this synchronous block? Or can I just leave it blank and it'll inject an empty call at the end of the processing queue?

Comment: @remus - I think you can leave it as nothing and it will still work, but you might need to check that to see that the compiler doesn't optimize it out. Maybe do meaningless calculation there. The `glFinish()` that henryl suggests isn't fully safe, since that can cause a crash if the OpenGL ES context hasn't been attached to the particular thread that block runs on.

Comment: Awesome - going to test this out tonight. Thanks!